PermissionsService.RequestPermissions() not working correctly to grant permissions to read/write files
On Android, the user needs to give permission to write and read a file. This code worked without problems in Delphi 10.4. But in Delphi 12.1, when opening the application, a window does not appear to give permission, but immediately jumps to the PermissionRequestResult procedure and, when checking, respectively, since permission is not given, displays the window "Required permissions have not been received".
Can you tell me what's wrong with the code?
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,System.Permissions,
  Androidapi.Jni.Os,Fmx.DialogService,
  Androidapi.Helpers;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject;const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
    procedure ExplainReason(Sender: TObject; const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FPermissionWrite: string;
    FPermissionRead: string;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.ExplainReason(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray; const APostRationaleProc: TProc);
begin
  TDialogService.ShowMessage('Приложению нужен доступ к карте памяти для таких то целей',
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      APostRationaleProc;
    end)
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FPermissionWrite := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
  FPermissionRead := JStringToString(TJManifest_permission.JavaClass.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PermissionsService.RequestPermissions([FPermissionWrite, FPermissionRead], PermissionRequestResult, ExplainReason);
end;

procedure TForm1.PermissionRequestResult(Sender: TObject;
  const APermissions: TClassicStringDynArray;
  const AGrantResults: TClassicPermissionStatusDynArray);
begin
  if (Length(AGrantResults) = 2) and (AGrantResults[0] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) and (AGrantResults[1] = TPermissionStatus.Granted) then
  begin
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Разрешения получены');
  end
  else begin
    TDialogService.ShowMessage('Требуемые разрешения не получены');
  end;
end;

end.


This question is similar to: Delphi Rio fails to read external storage with READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions set. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@whosrdaddy the OP is already doing what that answer suggests to do. So how is that question a duplicate?

I suspect this has nothing to do with the Delphi version, but rather the Android version of the device in which the app runs, as storage permissions changed their behavior in the last years. That info, and the target API level of the app, could give some insight.

@RemyLebeau: agreed but the code in the answer of the linked question is a bit different regarding requesting permissions (albeit very subtle), maybe the OP can try that.

@whosrdaddy that code is requesting only read permission, and using an anonymous procedure to get the response. This code is requesting read and write permissions, and using class methods. Those differences don't matter in this case. I agree with Alex, this is likely due to an API  behavioral change. More detail about the app setup is needed.

@RemyLebeau: Ok I get it, removed the vote.
